Reindex to expand and fill value only across one level of multi-index
I have a dataframe with an index of (month, A, B):
                       foo  N
month      A B               
1983-03-01 3 9           0  1
1983-06-01 3 9           0  1
1983-09-01 3 9           0  1
1983-11-01 4 5           0  1
1984-05-01 4 5           0  1
1984-06-01 3 9           0  1
1984-09-01 3 9           0  2

I would like to fill all missing dates, provided that a certain (A, B) combination exists in the index. What I do not want to do is to fill in the index for all (A, B) combinations.
That is, I would like to have for (A=3, B=9) and for (A=4, B=5) month-indices running from 1983-03-01 to 1984-09-01 and 0s for filling. But I don't want there to be any records of (A=3, B=5) or (A=4, B=9).
If this was a single index, I could simply
idx = pd.date_range(df['month'].min(), df['month'].max(), freq='M')
df = df.set_index('month')
df.index = df.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)

How would I approach it in this situation?
Worth noting that this solution should scale with a large number of unique values for A, B.

Kindly add the expected output dataframe

I believe I have guessed the correct output here, see my edit to my answer. Otherwise some sample output would be appreciated.

Assuming:
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': pd.to_datetime(['1983-03-01', '1983-06-01', '1983-09-01', '1983-11-01', '1984-05-01', '1984-06-01', '1984-09-01']),
                   'A': [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3],
                   'B': [9, 9, 9, 5, 5, 9, 9],
                   'foo': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'N': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]}
                 )

You could use a groupby.apply:
cols = df.columns.difference(['month', 'A', 'B'])

out = (df.set_index('month').groupby(['A', 'B'])[cols]
         .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(x.index.get_level_values('month').min(),
                                                  x.index.get_level_values('month').max(),
                                                  freq='MS').rename('month'),
                                    fill_value=0))
         .reset_index()[df.columns]
      )

Output:
        month  A  B  foo  N
0  1983-03-01  3  9    0  1
1  1983-04-01  3  9    0  0
2  1983-05-01  3  9    0  0
3  1983-06-01  3  9    0  1
4  1983-07-01  3  9    0  0
5  1983-08-01  3  9    0  0
6  1983-09-01  3  9    0  1
7  1983-10-01  3  9    0  0
8  1983-11-01  3  9    0  0
9  1983-12-01  3  9    0  0
10 1984-01-01  3  9    0  0
11 1984-02-01  3  9    0  0
12 1984-03-01  3  9    0  0
13 1984-04-01  3  9    0  0
14 1984-05-01  3  9    0  0
15 1984-06-01  3  9    0  1
16 1984-07-01  3  9    0  0
17 1984-08-01  3  9    0  0
18 1984-09-01  3  9    0  2
19 1983-11-01  4  5    0  1
20 1983-12-01  4  5    0  0
21 1984-01-01  4  5    0  0
22 1984-02-01  4  5    0  0
23 1984-03-01  4  5    0  0
24 1984-04-01  4  5    0  0
25 1984-05-01  4  5    0  1


I hadn't considered grouping by something else than the index - very nifty!

I tried to implement this with my actual data, where I have ~350 unique values for A and B respectively -- this doesn't scale very well since it iteratively goes through all the groups. Is there an alternative?

You have to loop over each group to find the min/max date in any case. It might be possible to parallelize using parallel_pandas since the operations are independent.

You can also try a groupby(…).resample(…).asfreq() pattern here which can expand a monthly frequency within each groupby grouping.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'month': pd.to_datetime(['1983-03-01', '1983-06-01', '1983-09-01', '1983-11-01', '1984-05-01', '1984-06-01', '1984-09-01']),
    'A': [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3],
    'B': [9, 9, 9, 5, 5, 9, 9],
    'foo': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'N': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
})

non_grouping_cols = df.columns.difference(['month', 'A', 'B'])
print(
    df.set_index('month')
    .groupby(['A', 'B']).resample('MS')[non_grouping_cols].asfreq(fill_value=0)
    .reset_index()
)
#     A  B      month  N  foo
# 0   3  9 1983-03-01  1    0
# 1   3  9 1983-04-01  0    0
# 2   3  9 1983-05-01  0    0
# 3   3  9 1983-06-01  1    0
# 4   3  9 1983-07-01  0    0
# 5   3  9 1983-08-01  0    0
# 6   3  9 1983-09-01  1    0
# 7   3  9 1983-10-01  0    0
# 8   3  9 1983-11-01  0    0
# 9   3  9 1983-12-01  0    0
# 10  3  9 1984-01-01  0    0
# 11  3  9 1984-02-01  0    0
# 12  3  9 1984-03-01  0    0
# 13  3  9 1984-04-01  0    0
# 14  3  9 1984-05-01  0    0
# 15  3  9 1984-06-01  1    0
# 16  3  9 1984-07-01  0    0
# 17  3  9 1984-08-01  0    0
# 18  3  9 1984-09-01  2    0
# 19  4  5 1983-11-01  1    0
# 20  4  5 1983-12-01  0    0
# 21  4  5 1984-01-01  0    0
# 22  4  5 1984-02-01  0    0
# 23  4  5 1984-03-01  0    0
# 24  4  5 1984-04-01  0    0
# 25  4  5 1984-05-01  1    0


If you want the existing groups (of A, B) to persist and for them to have
all of the same daterange (from min(month) to max(month)) you can create
your own MultiIndex from the cross-join between these two parts.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'month': pd.to_datetime(['1983-03-01', '1983-06-01', '1983-09-01', '1983-11-01', '1984-05-01', '1984-06-01', '1984-09-01']),
    'A': [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3],
    'B': [9, 9, 9, 5, 5, 9, 9],
    'foo': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'N': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
})

months = pd.date_range(df['month'].min(), df['month'].max(), freq='MS', name='month')
groupings = df[['A', 'B']].drop_duplicates()
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(groupings.merge(months.to_frame(), how='cross'))

print(
    df.set_index(['A', 'B', 'month']).reindex(index, fill_value=0)
)
                foo  N
# A B month
# 3 9 1983-03-01    0  1
#     1983-04-01    0  0
#     1983-05-01    0  0
#     1983-06-01    0  1
#     1983-07-01    0  0
#     1983-08-01    0  0
#     1983-09-01    0  1
#     1983-10-01    0  0
#     1983-11-01    0  0
#     1983-12-01    0  0
#     1984-01-01    0  0
#     1984-02-01    0  0
#     1984-03-01    0  0
#     1984-04-01    0  0
#     1984-05-01    0  0
#     1984-06-01    0  1
#     1984-07-01    0  0
#     1984-08-01    0  0
#     1984-09-01    0  2
# 4 5 1983-03-01    0  0
#     1983-04-01    0  0
#     1983-05-01    0  0
#     1983-06-01    0  0
#     1983-07-01    0  0
#     1983-08-01    0  0
#     1983-09-01    0  0
#     1983-10-01    0  0
#     1983-11-01    0  1
#     1983-12-01    0  0
#     1984-01-01    0  0
#     1984-02-01    0  0
#     1984-03-01    0  0
#     1984-04-01    0  0
#     1984-05-01    0  1
#     1984-06-01    0  0
#     1984-07-01    0  0
#     1984-08-01    0  0
#     1984-09-01    0  0


This might be the most performant, since resample is optimised on groupby

@sammywemmy but it doesn't work as expected -- resample here only fills holes within each group, but it doesnt make sure that they all have the same common start/end date.

Can you expand more on this? The displayed output matches that of your expected output as well as the other answers here.

@FooBar if you want the same start and end date, then a groupby is not required. Besides, the answer here is the same as mozway's

@sammywemmy that's right, I didnt even notice it there!
